# Swagger Multiple Examples Not Showing

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

When I add examples into my swagger doc and test it on the swagger editor, then it never shows anywhere. Could someone give me an example of where multiple examples are actually showing anywhere?

Here is an example of how multiple examples are added:
[image]

it is from: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/adding-examples/

Here is an example of yaml that does not display any `examples` on the online swagger editor:

```
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: Some API
  version: 1.0.0
paths:
  /logon:
    get:
      summary: Login user
      tags:
        - '/logon'
      parameters:
        - name: Client
          in: query
          required: true
          examples:
            zero:
              value: '0'
              summary: A sample limit value
            max:
              value: '50'
              summary: A sample limit value
          schema:
            type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Success response
```

Comment: Related: [Swagger/OpenAPI 3.0 issue with example on responses](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48551855/113116)

Answer (score 9):

Multiple `examples` are displayed in Swagger UI 3.23.0+ and Swagger Editor 3.6.21+:

[image: Swagger UI displays multiple examples using a drop-down list]

In older versions, you can use a single `example` as a workaround:

```yaml
      parameters:
        - name: Client
          in: query
          required: true
          example: '50'  # <-----
          schema:
            type: string
```

Comment: Oh wow ok. Makes you wonder why they put it in the documentation when it doesn't show. Really very disappointed with Swagger. I wish they weren't the industry standard. I constantly battle to get stuff to work without good documentation....sorry for the rant. Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: @FreddyBonda rendering of multiple `examples` is now available in the latest version of Swagger UI.

Comment: ...but it still does not seem to work on their [editor.swagger.io](https://editor.swagger.io/)  webpage. Seems to be using version 3.0.20.

Comment: @user9645 https://editor.swagger.io uses Swagger Editor v. 3.8.3 which does support multiple `examples`. If something does not work for you, [ask a new question](/questions/ask) and post an API definition (YAML or JSON) to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Helen - I generated the nodejs-server download and found a file in there called VERSION which had "3.0.20" in it - I assumed that was the version... anyway - I [asked a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62088926/1571426).

Comment: Anyone facing issue in seeing example in the HTML generated file? Can anyone help me? I can see the example in Swagger editor, but not in HTML file.